# Identical notification bubbles keep re-appearing

Tags: 12.04, notification

I have just recently noticed this problem occurring. When I receive an email, the on-screen notification bubbles 'keep popping up'. By this, I mean it will pop-up and tell me I have received an email, then it will disappear, and an identical bubble, telling me about the same email, will pop-up again. This will happen anywhere between 4-9 times. As you can imagine, it is getting pretty annoying, especially considering the volume of emails one receives these days.

I have ubuntu 12.04, and have installed notify-OSD, but have only used it to change the position and 'click to dismiss' properties of the bubbles. I have thunderbird (with my gmail account in it) and lightning installed (but only use TB to interact with my gmail calendar). I also use Chromium to check my gmail.

Has anyone got any ideas of what may be causing this? Is it a Chromium extension problem, or a thunderbird problem, or an OS/notification daemon problem?

Cheers,
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I have figured out what was wrong, and how to fix it.

I had installed Unity Webapps extension (e.g. to integrate Youtube, Google Docs, etc into the desktop). I had a look in my Chromium extensions, and there was 4 unity webapps extensions installed. I disabled 3 of them, and now the email pop-up only occurs once!

If anyone else has this problem, this is exactly how I fixed it:

In Chromium, go Tools>Extensions. Then, ensure only one (1) Unity WebApps Chromium extension is enabled.